# ib_insync error (can noy connect to TWS IB)

Tags: python, interactive-brokers, ib-insync

yesterday my code was working fine, but today without any reason for me (and no changes to the code) I can not connect to Interactive Brokers TWS via ib_insync

The code itself is longer but error appears after I try to connect to IB

Code is:

```
from ib_insync import IB

ib = IB()
ib.connect('127.0.0.1', 7497, clientId=1, readonly=True)
```

Error messege is:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\Yar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\tasks.py",
> line 458, in wait_for
> fut.result() asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\Yar\PycharmProjects\positionkeeping2\err.py", line 4, in
>
> ib.connect('127.0.0.1', 7497, clientId=1, readonly=True)   File "C:\Users\Yar\PycharmProjects\positionkeeping2\venv\lib\site-packages\ib_insync\ib.py",
> line 279, in connect
> return self._run(self.connectAsync(   File "C:\Users\Yar\PycharmProjects\positionkeeping2\venv\lib\site-packages\ib_insync\ib.py",
> line 318, in _run
> return util.run(*awaitables, timeout=self.RequestTimeout)   File "C:\Users\Yar\PycharmProjects\positionkeeping2\venv\lib\site-packages\ib_insync\util.py",
> line 341, in run
> result = loop.run_until_complete(task)   File "C:\Users\Yar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py",
> line 641, in run_until_complete
> return future.result()   File "C:\Users\Yar\PycharmProjects\positionkeeping2\venv\lib\site-packages\ib_insync\ib.py",
> line 1782, in connectAsync
> await asyncio.wait_for(self.reqExecutionsAsync(), timeout)   File "C:\Users\Yar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\tasks.py",
> line 460, in wait_for
> raise exceptions.TimeoutError() from exc asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError

I have tried to reisntall TWS API, reboot the computer etc - nothing has helped.
I have checked all the API settings - they are correct (7497 - port, ActiveX and Socket Clients Enebled)

Also the following code (which uses ibapi) is workig fine and connects to TWS. So I can connect to TWS via ibapi bit not via ib_insync

```
from ibapi.client import *
from ibapi.wrapper import *

class TestApp(EClient, EWrapper):
    def __init__(self):
        EClient.__init__(self, self)
        self.instrument = None
        self.bid_price = None
        self.ask_price = None

    def nextValidId(self, orderId: int):
        self.reqMarketDataType(1)
        self.reqMktData(orderId, self.instrument, "", True, 0, [])

    def tickPrice(self, reqId, tickType, price, attrib):
        if tickType == 1:  # Bid Price
            self.bid_price = price
        elif tickType == 2:  # Ask Price
            self.ask_price = price

        if self.bid_price is not None and self.ask_price is not None:
            print(f"{self.bid_price} / {self.ask_price}")
            print(f'ReqId: {reqId}')
            self.cancelMktData(reqId)
            self.disconnect()


def mainProc ():
    instrument_data = {"symbol": "NG", "secType": "FUT", "exchange": "NYMEX", "currency": "USD", "lastTradeDateOrContractMonth": 202306}

    app = TestApp()
    app.connect("127.0.0.1", 7497, 1)

    contract = Contract()
    contract.symbol = instrument_data["symbol"]
    contract.secType = instrument_data["secType"]
    contract.exchange = instrument_data["exchange"]
    contract.currency = instrument_data["currency"]
    contract.lastTradeDateOrContractMonth = instrument_data["lastTradeDateOrContractMonth"]
    app.instrument = contract

    app.run()
    app.disconnect()


mainProc()
```

Comment: so you can make HTTP request, but unable to use websocket ?

Answer (score 1):

Change to STABLE version. File -> Change Version -> Stable